# Are there any Carsten Höller slides in museums/galleries in Central or Eastern Europe?

Tags: europe, where-on-earth, eastern-europe, central-europe, artworks

A few years ago, the artist [Carsten Höller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carsten_H%C3%B6ller) installed some slides in the turbine hall of the Tate Modern gallery in London. These looked really good, but sadly were insanely popular and I never got the chance to try them out. (The Tate Modern changes the installation piece in the Turbine Hall fairly regularly)

[image: Tate Modern slides from wikipedia, note the queues! en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Carsten_holler_tate.jpg]

As I understand it, the slides in the Tate Modern weren't Carsten's [only](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carsten_H%C3%B6ller#Select_works.2C_projects.2C_and_exhibitions) piece on that theme, and others have been done too. This means there's still a chance for me to try them out elsewhere!

In the near future, I'll be visiting a few places in Central and Eastern Europe. Do I have any hope of finding one of his slide installations open and working at a museum or gallery in that region?

Comment: This looks fun! As this being self-answered question, I would have liked to see this asked for the whole world instead of just Europe.

Comment: We discussed it on chat, and it was felt that the whole world would result in a "too list like" question, so the suggestion was to limit it to just one (broad-ish) area. If you think that's the wrong call, meta is the place to discuss / debate it! :)

Comment: I would agree with that if we asked where to find escalators, but I somehow doubt that there are more than 5 places where you can find such a slide.

Comment: Meta is the right place to ask this sort of thing, so there's a record and clarity!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is at least one such place! The [Museum of Contemporary Art (MSU)](http://www.msu.hr/#/en/) in [Zagreb, Croatia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Museum_of_Contemporary_Art,_Zagreb) has two of his slides installed in a double helix!

[image: Picture of the slides from September 2013]

One entrance to the slides is from the second floor, near where you enter the permanent collection. The other is on the third floor, at the end of the collection.

This has the effect that if you tour the permanent collection in the recommended order, you'll get to the end right by the entrance to the higher of the two slides, and can have a fun + unusual trip back to the entrance! (There's a staff member near the entrance to hand you a mat to go down on). Alternately, if you just want to enjoy the slide, go up the stairs from the ticket office into the gallery, turn left and left again, then take the shorter slide straight back down again. Wwhheeee! :)

Unlike at the Tate Modern, there was no queue when I came to have a go. The rest of the museum was excellent too, so it's well worth going anyway, and the  Carsten Höller slides prove an added bonus!

Comment: did you visit the museum in 15 minutes?

Comment: Several hours! Took a bit of time on chat to get a consensus on how to form it into a good question though...